# Add keyboard shortcuts to Windows+X menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-terminal

I added Windows Terminal, as well its administrator version, to my <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> menu using [Win+X Menu Editor](https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.30) after following [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TotallyUnsupportedHacksAddWindowsTerminalToTheWinXShortcutMenu.aspx) and [this](http://nuts4.net/post/windows-terminal-run-as-admin)
How can I add a keyboard shortcut, similarly to that I can open PowerShell using <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> → i?

My current <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer this should solve it for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer to also reflect explanation to add own/custom keys**

There are already shortcuts attached. Please check my screenshot (from a German Windows version). You can see the underlined "letters" which do show the shortcut for the respective elements. The underlining of the letters only happens when hitting <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Examples (for the first four elements of the menu):

- <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Apps und Features)
- <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Mobilitätscenter)
- <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (Energieoptionen)
- <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (Ereginisanzeige)

[image: Windows+X menu: Before]

If you want to attach your own keyboard key to an item add it with [Win+X Menu Editor](https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.30).

1. Open "Add a program" > "Add a program".

[image: Win+X Menu Editor: Add a program]

2. Select the desired program.

[image: File Explorer's file selector]

3. Give the new entry a name e.g. "ExtractWi&zard" (with an ampersand before your desired key).

[image: Renaming the new item - adding an ampersand before the shortcut letter]

And we are done!

[image: Win+X Menu Editor after renaming the shortcut program]

This gives you the shortcut combination <kbd>*⊞* Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: Windows+X menu: After]

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough in the main post. I added Windows Terminal to that menu and I want to add a shortcut to it

Comment: @avi12 Why do you need to rebind? There should be already a shortcut combination. Please also read my post. I updated it.

Comment: Not really. If you add another item, no shortcut is bound to it by default

Comment: @avi12 Can you please add a screenshot to your original post showing your Win+X menu after hitting Win+X

Comment: Added the requested screenshot

Comment: @avi12 Thanks for posting. I will update my question.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @avi12 Glad that it worked for you :-)! You are welcome!

Comment: Where do you insert the &? Be clear and include each and every step, don’t submit incomplete answers.

Comment: @Valay_17 Don't get me wrong but the answer was far away from "incomplete". Every human able to read and understand English should be able to understand what is going on. The OP already included a adequate tooling in his question so actually no necessity to reiterate every step but nonetheless I updated the question to be a step by step explanation for people also facing the same problem.

Comment: @thex Thank You So Much for updating the answer, actually I couldn’t understand how he added the &.

Comment: @Valay_17 You're welcome, Sorry, I assumed it was already quite clear how it was originally stated. My reaction was also quite a bit harsh. But now we have the full step by step solution which is great. Thanks for the input :)!

Comment: @thex Never mind, together we all work to improve this site after all :)

Comment: @Valay_17 you are totally right :-).

Comment: @thex I must agree with you. By the moment that you mentioned the `&` before the letter, I immediately knew what I need to do. The thing is, not all users understand UX equally

Comment: @avi12 It was definitively a plus mentioning the lack of information so that it is now easier for other users to understand how to use the tool. I sometimes overlook that users might not have the same understanding!